# Is Donald Trump experiencing a rally 'round the flag event?

Tags: united-states, president, donald-trump, public-opinion

According to FiveThirtyEight, Trump's approval is up from 40% to 43%, or 3 percentage points. (His disapproval of course, is down by a similar margin.)

I believe that the president could be experiencing a rally round the flag effect. I say so because it seems statistically significant and started in the beginning of August. Is there anything that could plausibly be triggering this rally?

Comment: The usual post-convention bounce?

Comment: Possibly. But Biden *also* had a convention and it started before the convention.

Comment: That is not true. It was at 40-44% except when covid started. Look at Hoover. I think it cant be the same degree but it'll be big by modern standards.

Comment: And who attacked us that we're rallying against? Did I miss something big?

Answer (score 3):

These are very small movements, probably within the margin of error.

The most recent up-tick is mostly due to a Emerson college poll that put Trump approval on 48.  This may be an outlier, it may be a post-convention bounce, or it may be the start of a trend. Only time will tell. Emerson is highly ranked pollster and this is a poll of likely voters, not all adults, which gives it greater weight in the 538 model.

Moreover for a true "rally round the flag" there needs to be some sort of military action, or similar crisis. Perhaps the rioting falls into this category.  However at the moment this is a single poll. If other polls come out telling the same story, especially if they are supported by specific approval for Trumps handling of the riots and protests, then *perhaps* it might be seen in retrospect as a "rally around the flag".

If you want to see what "rally round the flag" looks like, look at George W. Bush's approval.  on the 10th of September 2001 it was about 52% approve. On the 12th it was over 80% approval and remained elevated for more than a year.

Trumps approval has been very static. It has remained between 40 and 45 for nearly the whole of his Presidency.

Comment: That is true. But a similar thing happened around the start of Covid-19. Trump's approval was up 4 percentage points when the Covid crisis started and then since evaporated. This is a polarized era.

Comment: Most of emerson's responses came from Mechanical Turk, literally. The rest came from landlines, remember those? ["_Data was collected using an Interactive Voice Response (IVR) system of landlines (n=770) and an online panel provided by MTurk (n=797)._"](https://emersonpolling.reportablenews.com/pr/august-2020-presidential-race-tightens-after-party-conventions)

Comment: Indeed, however it is highly weighted in the 583 model (weighting of 2.19)

Comment: @dandavis That's surprising. Do you know if that means they got MTurk users to process the phone call data, or they got data from asking people on MTurk?